# Which (if any) mission changes are predetermined?

Tags: warframe

Sometimes missions will change partway through, like getting additional objectives, ice damage, a second faction joining the fight and so on. Some of these happen randomly (I'm sure the environmental ones are), while others seem to always occur on certain assignments: for example, Earth:Mantle will always have Corpus invade about halfway to the objective.

Which ones occur randomly, and which are designed as part of a mission? Is there any overlap between the two?

**Note:** this question was originally asked before invasions happened. Random events seem to be much less common in the current version, but still seem to happen occasionally. It seems that they're much more heavily related to specific circumstances. What are those circumstances for each kind of mission variable?

Answer (score 0):

While some are procs (Programmed Occurrences), many are only random. Some alert missions will have a random shift programmed in, others will have a high chance of this happening.

Also, some objective may be 'duplicated' during a mission. For example, there have been cases of Rescue missions having as many as 3 captives to rescue, or a Sabotage mission having 2 reactors.

Comment: Pretty sure this is incorrect usage of "proc".